# How to sanitize the query string input against cross site scripting - reflected issues in ASP .Net (Web Forms) Application?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, xss, query-string, websecurity

I am working on a legacy Application which has some **cross site scripting - reflected** issues when we take the input from query string. The issues are being reported by Fortify code scan (WebInspect) tool.

For example:

I have a page called ProgressDisplay.aspx which takes reportPath as a query string parameter.

```
/ReportViewer/ProgressDisplay.aspx?reportPath=%27%3b%61%6c%65%72%74%28%35%36%36%34%35%29%2f%2f
```

In the above code reportPath is a query string parameter where the malicious payload is being passed which shows an alert in the response.

Above payload becomes `alert(56645)` after rendering.

Like this, there are several similar issues are being reported. Is there any centralized approach to fix all the issues at one shot by using any ASP .Net library Or making some changes in the config instead of fixing each issue Or I'll have to fix all the issue one by one?

**After the fix, the page shouldn't return the response as 200 when a malicious script is inserted. We have to return a Bad Request in response.**

Answer (score 0):

Use below recommendation to avoid Cross site scripting attack in Microsoft.NET Language :

**URL Encoding** : It prevent malicious script from being injected into a URL.

*Not: You can use Microsoft Web Protection Library (WPL) to avoid all xss-Reflected issues.*

eg: `<a href=<%# Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.UrlEncode(TEST.Url) %>>View Details</a>`

**Enabling a Content Security Policy (CSP)**
**Validated Input data**:Input data should be validated Before execute.
[XSS- Microsoft.NET](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-xss)

**Encode data on output**